# Creating a Scatter Graph using Scripting for Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, charts

Google sheet and script: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Vq2MYQzbaRoYg31IRkwNOofJYYOH82ElSdN7miExiVQ/edit?usp=sharing

I currently am trying to create a scatter graph using data that I have been given but only using script, so I am making this scatter graph based on the data in B15 tp W16 but this data is placed in these cells by using the new applied menubar option called "Apply Script".

So if you click:

**Apply Script > Activate Script**

This will change the cell sizes, change the font size, create a conditional format for the data within cells C3 to W13, and will create a key for the data as well.

Then if you click:

**Apply Script > Select Power Input > Select any option**

Once you select which row of data you want to view, it'll be applied with cells B15 to W16 (It will make more sense if you try it yourself).

These functions will be applied to any given data that is active, I have 3 sheets within the document below so it demonstrates this.

So now that I have explained how my scripting works so far, I want to know how to script a scatter graph using any given data that is cell B15 to W16. Everything I have demonstrated above is all that I have taught myself in the past 3 days watching videos but I can't find any demonstrations for creating a chart on google scripting anywhere, I have also searched through script.google.com to find the coding needed but I couldn't understand where to start and how to present it. So if anyone can point me in the right direction that'll be great, thank you!

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Vq2MYQzbaRoYg31IRkwNOofJYYOH82ElSdN7miExiVQ/edit?usp=sharing

This is my existing chart script:

```
function lineGraph() {

 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
 var row = sheet.getRange( 15, 2, 2, 22).getValues();
  
  sheet.newChart().addRange().asScatterChart().getChartType().SCATTER;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script is certainly in the right direction, but you have to specify where to place your chart in the sheet by using `setPosition`.

Also, I added some options for the generated chart to make more sense based on your input.

**Sample Code:**

```
function lineGraph() {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var row = sheet.getRange("B15:W16");
  var chart = sheet.newChart()
    .asScatterChart()
    .addRange(row)
    .setPosition(18,2,0,0)
    .setTransposeRowsAndColumns(true)
    .build();
  sheet.insertChart(chart);

}
```

**Sample Output:**

[image]

Note that this is bare bones, you can specify more options by adding more methods onto the chartBuilder. Please see reference here:

[Embedded Scatter Chart Builder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-scatter-chart-builder)

Comment: OMG you're a lifesaver thank you!!! I still need to add titles and create a linear line in the data but how you've demonstrated it is an amazing starting point!!!